# Powershell foreach statement not working

Tags: powershell

I have this foreach statement that goes through a list of usernames and puts each name in the path listed below, then it copies and pastes a file to the individual users startup folder. For some reason i get an error that a portion of the path was not found. Any ideas what the problem could be?

```
#for each username folder copy the a file to the users startup folder
foreach ($_ in $usernames)
{
$destination = "C:\users\"+ "$_" + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp\file.bat -destination $destination -force
}
```

I have tried changing the way the path for my $destination variable is written and i get the same results

Comment: $_ is an automatic variable.  You should probably not use it for your loop "counter".

Comment: Which Windows version/network? For instance, in a non-domain environment, the code snippet should run smoothly in an **elevated** PowerShell console.

Comment: @JosefZ windows 7 domain joined clients

Answer (score 3):

A couple of issues with this:

1) `foreach ($_ in $usernames)`.  Its really bad practise to try and inject into a pipeline variable and can be unpredictable at best.  Instead try something like `ForEach($username in $usernames)`

2) your string build for `$destination` could do with better formatting.  try something like `$destination = "'C:\users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'"`

3) Indentation - makes it easier to read

Putting it all together - you get something like:

```
foreach ($username in $usernames)
{
    $destination = "'C:\users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'"
    Copy-Item -Path c:\temp\file.bat -destination $destination -force
}
```

---

For extra points:

- put the file you're copying into a variable for easier modifications or reuse
- look to add an error handler and make sure the path exists before you try the copy

You then end up with something that looks like this:

```
$sourceFile = "C:\temp\file.bat"
foreach ($username in $usernames)
{
    $destination = "'C:\users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'"
    if (Test-Path $destination) {
        try {
            Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -destination $destination -force
            Write-Host "Copy Completed"
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Copy to $destination Failed"
        }

    } else {
        Write-Host "$destination Does Not Exist"
    }
}
```

You'll now be told if each copy succeeds, fails because the path doesnt exist or fails because the copy fails (access denied or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is interesting. I got to looking at the error message which again read as follows:

```
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\
                                                Public\AppData\Roaming\Micros oft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'
```

So i realized that all the space between c:\users\ and Public was just white space. So i edited my list to remove all the white space after each username and after that it works.